# Adjusting vector lines in pgfornament

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfornament

I create an ornamented vector line using pgfornament. Suprisingly there appears second straight line beneath the ornamented vector line. How can I avoid it?

Minimum example:

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{book}
 \usepackage{pgfornament}
 \begin{document}
 \pagenumbering{gobble}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (A) at (0,0) {};\node (B) at (16,0) {};
 \draw [blue] (A)  to [ornament=89]   (B);\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \clearpage
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\path[blue] (A) to[ornament=89] (B);`, this will not draw the path and just adds the ornament. This is a restriction of `to` path operation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I consider the question answered.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because answered in comment.